# How to use a favicon with ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, favicon, ember-cli

I had a favicon working for a while on my index template, but not any any other template, and now even my index template won't show it.

I'm just in development, so I'm using `ember server`.

index.html
`<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">`

Just throwing around my favicon to see if it shows up anywhere, I now have it in the following locations:

`app/
public/
public/assets`

I think this should be very straightforward, especially since the index page doesn't change, just get's new stuff loaded into its outlets, so I can't figure out why it can't find my favicon file.

When running `ember server`, where actually is the `/` root pointing to?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you keep the favicon file in `public/assets/` you can reference it like this:

`<link rel="icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">`

[The Ember CLI docs have a good section on this](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#asset-compilation)

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was mostly some temporary Firefox error. When I restarted, the favicon popped up in the tab.

Comment: I'm confused, where do I put the link tag? I don't have a `<head>` tag anywhere.

Comment: You should have one in `app/index.html` if you are using `ember-cli` @EricWilson

Comment: For me (using ember-cli: 3.25.2), index.html >> BEFORE `{{content-for "head"}}`  >> `<link rel="icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">` DID NOT WORK.  HOWEVER index.html >> AFTER `{{content-for "head"}}`  >> `<link rel="icon" href="{{rootURL}}assets/favicon.ico">`DID WORK.

Answer (score 7):

You could also check out [ember-cli-favicon](https://github.com/davewasmer/ember-cli-favicon).

It's an addon that takes your source `public/favicon.png` and automatically outputs all the different favicon formats and sizes for different devices, as well as injects the appropriate HTML into your `index.html` file as part of the build process.