# How to link to favicon in ember-cli application?

Tags: ember.js, favicon, ember-cli

I want to include a favicon in an ember-cli application. I have put the `.ico` image in `/public/assests/img/`, and am able to include that image in a page.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648827/how-to-use-a-favicon-with-ember-cli) I'm on the right track, but ...

Where would I like to the favicon? Normally I would put:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/assets/img/favicon.ico">
```

in the `head` of a html file. What `.hbs` file should contain a `head`? I'm new to ember and ember-cli, but I thought that the hbs files were just partials of HTML files. I have tried to throw the `link` tag into the `application.hbs` file, but that doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just add it to the `app/index.html` file, directly in the `<head>`. There might be a way to add it to `{{content-for 'head'}}` within the application initializer but I'm not entirely sure myself.

Comment: That was silly. I forgot there was an `index.html`, as I hadn't touched it. Thanks much.

Comment: I checked on the `{{content-for 'head'}}` option. You'd have to use an addon to gain access to the `contentFor` hook. Such as `ember generate in-repo-addon favicon`, then return it form the `contentFor` hook when the `type` is "head". http://www.ember-cli.com/#content So yeah, just adding it to your `app/index.html` file is easier.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ember-cli-favicon](https://github.com/davewasmer/ember-cli-favicon).

It's an addon that takes your source `public/favicon.png` and automatically outputs all the different favicon formats and sizes for different devices, as well as injects the appropriate HTML into your `index.html` file as part of the build process.

Comment: But you probably don't want to do that, because it adds an additional web service dependency to your builds (no offline builds), and can add a significant amount of time to the build.

Comment: @theazureshadow that's definitely true, and I tried calling that out in the readme. There are certainly tradeoffs. The reliance on a web service isn't great, but it does ensure you get the latest favicon specs for whatever new device format comes out tomorrow. And the significant build time should only happen when you actually change the favicon itself (which usually isn't that often). 

It may not be the right solution in all cases, but I know at least personally, I've found the benefits to outweigh the downsides.